# What are zkSNARK parameters and how to verify them?

Tags: verification, zcash, zero-knowledge

When installing the zcash client for the first time it downlods a bulk of around 900 MiB in zkSNARK parameters. I am wondering: why and what are they exactly used for? Is this a security feature? How to verify the parameters?

What are zkSNARK parameters and how to verify them?

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a zero knowledge proof that is easy to verify. The parameters are given on the zcash site. you can check it here
https://z.cash/blog/generating-zcash-parameters.html

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin Stack Exchange! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.